# ionic2/angular2 - Access an object in an external file in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am building a mobile app using ionic2.
For payments online i use a simple online payment service called Paystack.

it works by including a js file in your webpage and then calling a function

```
<script>
  function payWithPaystack(){
    var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
      key: 'UNIQUE_KEY_HERE',
      email: 'customer@email.com',
      amount: 10000,
      ref: "UNIQUE TRANSACTION REFERENCE HERE",
      metadata: {
         custom_fields: [
            {
                display_name: "Mobile Number",
                variable_name: "mobile_number",
                value: "+2348012345678"
            }
         ]
      },
      callback: function(response){
          alert('success. transaction ref is ' + response.reference);
      },
      onClose: function(){
          alert('window closed');
      }
    });
    handler.openIframe();
  }
</script>
```

I am trying to port this to my ionic app. The problem is that it doesn't recognise `PaystackPop` even though i included the js file in the index.html.

How can i resolve this? I'm guessing i have to somehow import `PaystackPop` the way i import other classes, but i have no idea how to go about this. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
All i had to do was declare `PaystackPop` at the top of the file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var PaystackPop: any;
```

Comment: This was helpful.